# How create MAUI application with Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, maui

I'm creating apps with my Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition for Windows 11 using MAUI. From my Windows laptop I can connect to the iMac. With that, I can test my app for Windows, Android and iOS, only simulators.

Because running a MAUI app on my laptop is very slow, I wanted to use my iMac to test the application on my iPhone and iPad (not just in the simulator) and the macCatalyst version that is not supported on Visual Studio for Windows.

There is no way to run the application and select the platform at all. I googled and I discovered that I must be unchecked the **Build with MSBuild on Mono**. So, I open the project's properties and the option was unchecked. So, I *checked* this option and now I can select the platform.

[image]

Now I'm able to select the platform. If I try to deploy on macCatalyst, I get the following error

> Error: Could not find any available provisioning profiles for MauiAdMob on iOS.

I can deploy on my physical device an app from Xcode. From Xcode I downloaded the provision files.

Finally, my questions:

- is the process to deploying an app very slow for you? I took at least 10 minutes to see the app in the iPhone Simulator
- do I have to register as an Apple Developer to deploy my apps on my iPhone? Why can I do it from Xcode?
- how can I test a macCatalyst application?

Comment: 1) very slow: unless it is the newest iMac, the current Mac Mini is probably much faster than it. 2) Once Xcode has downloaded profile to the iPhone, VS Mac should be able to see that device. Unplug it and plug it in again. BUT I've never tried without having an Apple developer ID. 3) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/mac-catalyst/cli

Comment: I have a Microsoft Surface 3 with 32 Gb of ram and the new iMac. I noticed that Visual Studio on the Windows machine is very slot after the last updates. Run Blazor and Maui apps is now particularly slow.

Comment: The error implies that your iPhone is not trusted, you may refer to [Manual provisioning for iOS apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vs) and [Automatic provisioning for iOS apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vs).